How to get localised String from LocalizedStringKey
I'm curious, does anyone know what the steps are to get from a LocalizedStringKey to a normal String in Swift? There are plenty of resources on the results of feeding in a LocalizedStringKey to SwiftUI initialisers, but I can't find anything that lets you reproduce the inner workings of SwiftUI to do the localization.
For example, consider the following code:
let greetingKey = LocalizedStringKey("Greeting")
let localGreeting: String = localize(greetingKey)
let fancyLocalGreeting = "\(localGreeting)"

Setting aside concerns about scandals caused by local interpretations of the thumbs-up symbol, how would we implement localize here?
There's at least one SO question asking something similar, but it doesn't have a satisfactory answer there after 4+ years. I'm hoping this simpler question will have better luck.

There is currently no way. LocalizedStringKey is very dependent on SwiftUI, and is practically unusable outside of it. Why do you want to do this? Is this related to your other question? If not, consider using something like LocalizedStringResource.

It is indeed. I'm just trying to find a different way to solve the same underlying problem, since the other question doesn't seem to have an answer. Since this is also a dead end, I'll look for a different avenue. Thanks for the confirmation! By the way, my code would be in a SwiftUI context, so I don't mind any solutions that depend on that, if they are exposed to us.

Are you just trying to create a localized string?

No. I'm implementing a view that takes in a LocalizedStringKey and will pass a modified version of it to a sub-view. Of course, you'd have to do localization before modification.

You can try something like this:
extension LocalizedStringKey {
    var stringKey: String? {
        Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first(where: { $0.label == "key" })?.value as? String
    }
}

Basically, you would need to do greetingKey.stringKey to get the localized version of it. I don't remember where I found it and if I do I will link the sourse (probably another stack question, it did this quite a while ago). If I remember, it is not very efficent overall, but it gets the job done. Hope this works for you!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So far as I can see, this is only exposing the Key for the localisation - not getting the result. I only get "Greetings", rather then "Saludos" that I may have supplied to a Spanish localisation I have active. Could you verify that this works for you in your setup?
